# Sass options in Rails when installed as a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, rubygems, haml

I have Haml/Sass installed as a Gem and using it with Rails. I can't figure out, how to pass options like `template_location` and `style` to Sass. `Sass::Plugin.options` doesn't work (since Haml/Sass isn't installed as a plugin). The gem is required through `Rails::Initializer#gem`.

Answer (score 1):

`Sass::Plugin.options` should still work -- the "Plugin" refers to Sass being used with Rails, as opposed to standalone.